# How to Extract a Enum value from an NSDictionary in iOS obtained by parsing a JSON response

Tags: ios, json, enums, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I have a .net JSON web service which returns a json string when queried. I obtain that JSON string and parse it into a NSDictionary using SBJSON Parser. Now my .net web service adds an enum value to the response which when parsed into NSdictionary looks like this

"Name":0,

I need to extract this value on iOS client side. Any ideas how do I go about it.

I tried doing following things

```
int *val = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] intValue];
```

I know this is not the right way of doing this. I guess i need to store the result in an NSNumber object, But how do i extract an NSNumber value from NSDictionary.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: NSLog said NSDecimalNumber. So i got the value when i did this.
NSDecimalNumber val = [dictionary objectforkey:@"Name"];
Thanks for your help Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is valid.  The intermediate object you are pulling out and sending the intValue message is an NSNumber created by the json parser.  If you want an NSNumber, just do this instead:

```
    NSNumber *name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
```